# Measuring the turn around time of a request to server in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed an application in asp.net mvc5 , I want to measure the total time taken by a request (time from after clicking the button till view loads completely )

Is it possible in MVC 5 , if yes than how ?

Currently I am referring below link which suggest using Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest events in global file

[link here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Time_taken_to_render_a_page_in_ASP.NET.aspx)

Comment: What is your issue with the recommended solution ?

Comment: It is not showing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some profiling tools such as [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) or [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) can help you profiling your application, including request times (as seen by the client).

Comment: I found use of profiler very good in here , it show each and every file (css , js , images) loaded and their time too . Now I can see what is taking much time